# Consolidating duplicate Rows in R using ddply

Tags: r, plyr

Hi I am trying to combine duplicate rows of data in R using ddply.
Here is an example of the data I am working with:

```
name <- c("Bob", "Mary", "Bob", "Dillan", "Bob", "Mary")
age <- c(30, 20, 30, 25, 29, 20)
address <- c("123 Fake Street", "321 Park Ave", "123 Fake Street", "49 Rodeo Drive", "10 Broadway", "321 Park Ave")
election.count <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1")
df <- data.frame(name, age, address, election.count)

    name age             address election.count
1    Bob  30     123 Fake Street             1
2   Mary  20        321 Park Ave             1
3    Bob  30     123 Fake Street             1
4 Dillan  25      49 Rodeo Drive             1
5    Bob  29         10 Broadway             1
6   Mary  20        321 Park Ave             1
```

I am looking to combine rows with the same Name and Age. Using ddply I get

```
ddply(df, "name", numcolwise(sum))

    name age   election.count
1    Bob  89                3
2 Dillan  25                1
3   Mary  20                2
```

Is there a modification to ddply so I am able to get

```
    name age              address  election.count
1    Bob  30      123 Fake Street               1
2    Bob  29          10 Broadway               2
2 Dillan  25       49 Rodeo Drive               1
3   Mary  20         321 Park Ave               2
```

Comment: Is Mary 40 a typo? Are you summing ages?

Comment: Yes it is a typo I will correct that

Comment: I DONT wont the ages summed at all. That is one of the problems with my code.

Comment: They are two different people. Bob who is 30 is a different Bob who is 29

Comment: I apologize I corrected what I want my final output to look like.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't get the `election.count` output from the `ddply(df, "name", numcolwise(sum))` call, only `name` and `age` (as a sum).

That said, you can group by multiple columns in `plyr` functions using `.(col1, col2)` syntax. For example, I think this gets what you want:

```
ddply(df, .(name, age), nrow)
#     name age V1
# 1    Bob  29  1
# 2    Bob  30  2
# 3 Dillan  25  1
# 4   Mary  20  2
```

Comment: Thank you Max this actually works perfectly. I did not even think to have R create a new row with the number of times it found duplicates!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(name, age) %>% 
  tally()
```

and you get

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
Groups: name [?]

    name   age     n
    (fctr) (dbl) (int)
1    Bob    29     1
2    Bob    30     2
3 Dillan    25     1
4   Mary    20     2
```

Update:
@David is right. `count` is a much simpler choice. :)

Comment: Could also just do `df %>% count(name, age)`

Comment: @DavidRobinson Ahha, I almost forgot `count`. It's much better here.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the grouping variable 'address' also to get the expected output.  Using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'name', 'age', 'address', we get the nrow (`.N`).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(election.count=.N), .(name, age, address)]
#     name age         address election.count
#1:    Bob  30 123 Fake Street              2
#2:   Mary  20    321 Park Ave              2
#3: Dillan  25  49 Rodeo Drive              1
#4:    Bob  29     10 Broadway              1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the rownames.

```
ddply(df, .(name, age), summarize, election.count=nrow(piece))
#    name age election.count
# 1    Bob  29              1
# 2    Bob  30              2
# 3 Dillan  25              1
# 4   Mary  20              2
```